# Has anyone worked with a mobile robot simulation on terrain in Gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, base-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was wondering if anyone here has worked on a terrain robot (3D) in Gazebo simulation.
What I would like to know is,

- how to write a base controller so that it can travel on inclined planes and stay still without being dragged by the gravity when it stops.
  --> I implemented one similar to the pr2 base controller but it cannot do the above; need some help on this

Thank you in advance

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38153/has-anyone-worked-with-a-mobile-robot-simulation-on-terrain-in-gazebo?/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-07-06

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have uploaded (but not yet fully documented) our editor for easily creating NIST standard test arena scenarios (for example used for in the RoboCup Rescue competition) and assorted packages [here](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_nist_arenas_gazebo). You can check it out (currently only works for electric, fuerte branch will be updated later) and try

```
roslaunch hector_nist_arena_worlds go2011_arena.launch
```

This should spawn a gazebo version of the RoboCup German Open 2011 arena. It has multiple roll/pitch ramps and is used at [Team Hector](https://www.facebook.com/TeamHectorDarmstadt) to simulate our wheeled UGVs inside the arena.

Looks like this:

[image: image description]

With the [hector_nist_arena_designer](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_nist_arena_designer) you can even build other scenarios out of the available building blocks (walls, ramps, etc.) or define new building blocks (click on "help" in the editor for further info).

A hilly outdoor terrain is available in the [hector_gazebo_worlds](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_gazebo_worlds) package and can be started using

```
roslaunch hector_gazebo_worlds rolling_landscape_120m.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-07-23**:
Thank you very much @Stefan Kohlbrecher. However, I am looking for a base controller implementation, which is similar to PR2 (with casters, which makes the wheels steer). I can't keep my robot stationary on slopes. If someone has already implemented one, it would really help me to understand.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-07-23**:
Sorry, didn't get the question correctly. Do the casters rotate around the vertical axis on slopes or does the whole robot just slide down slopes with the casters staying in position?

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-07-24**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher casters stay in position-no problem with that.robot doesnt slide but the controller isnt capable of keeping the wheels locked (0velocity)when no motion command is given.actually in pr2 base controller it gives 0velocity to the wheel joint when no external motion command is given.

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-07-24**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher We can see this behavior if we try to move the PR2 on a ramp in gazebo. pr2 slowly moves down the ramp due to gravity. i know it is a problem with the base controller.I just need some help or some pointers how to implement it correctly.

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-07-25**:
Looks great, can't wait for the fuerte release